# Need to install libstdc++-5 on ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, library, gcc

I'm running ubuntu 9.10 which has gcc4 (libstdc++6) installed, and I need to install a program that requires libstdc++5 that comes with gcc3. I don't see gcc-3 listed when I run "apt-cache search" so:

- Is it necessary to install gcc-3 to achieve libstdc++5 ? If so where can I get it ?
- Is there a way to install just libstdc++5
- Would a soft link to libstdc++6 do or is it not recommended ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libstdc++5 isn't available in Ubuntu 9.10 (was available in universe in previous versions). You can try install the [jaunty version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/libstdc++5) - at a quick glance doesn't look like there'll be any dependency/conflict issues with that.

Comment: I agree: tried, works

Comment: I'm here trying to install libstdc++ on Ubuntu 10.04. The link here leads to an error page.

Comment: Jaunty is no longer supported, hence it has been removed from the ubuntu package site.